# How to loop through a nested hierarchy of NSDictionaries and NSArrays and convert all to mutable copies?

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSDictionary` that contains instances of many different types objects (`NSArrays`, `NSDictionaries`, `NSStrings`, `NSNumbers`, etc...). Many of the `NSDictionaries` and `NSStrings` have their own nested `NSDictionaries` and `NSArrays`.

How can I loop through the entire hierarchy, from top to bottom, and convert ALL instances of `NSDictionaries` and `NSArrays` to `NSMutableDictionaries` and `NSMutableArrays`, respectively?

Is there any easy "recursively make mutable copies" function I'm unaware of? If not, do I just need to loop and type check repeatedly? Can I just replace as I go or do I have rebuild the entire hierarchy?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following method creates a nested (deep) mutable copy of nested arrays, dictionaries and sets. It can also be used to create mutable copies of non-collection objects inside the hierarchy, such as strings.

```
@interface NSObject (MyDeepCopy)
-(id)deepMutableCopy;
@end

@implementation  NSObject (MyDeepCopy)
-(id)deepMutableCopy
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSArray *oldArray = (NSArray *)self;
        NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (id obj in oldArray) {
            [newArray addObject:[obj deepMutableCopy]];
        }
        return newArray;
    } else if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)self;
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (id obj in oldDict) {
            [newDict setObject:[oldDict[obj] deepMutableCopy] forKey:obj];
        }
        return newDict;
    } else if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSSet class]]) {
        NSSet *oldSet = (NSSet *)self;
        NSMutableSet *newSet = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (id obj in oldSet) {
            [newSet addObject:[obj deepMutableCopy]];
        }
        return newSet;
#if MAKE_MUTABLE_COPIES_OF_NONCOLLECTION_OBJECTS
    } else if ([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSMutableCopying)]) {
            // e.g. NSString
        return [self mutableCopy];
    } else if ([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCopying)]) {
            // e.g. NSNumber
        return [self copy];
#endif
    } else {
        return self;
    }
}
@end
```

Use it like

```
NSDictionary *dict = ...;
NSMutableDictionary *mdict = [dict deepMutableCopy];
```

(Dictionary keys are not copied, only the values).

I am quite sure that I have seen something like this on SO, but cannot find it right now.

Comment: What do you mean "keys are not copied"?

Comment: @yourfriendzak: For a dictionary `@{ key : value }` my code would create `@{ key : mutableCopyOfValue }`, and not `@{ mutableCopyOfKey : mutableCopyOfValue }` . Keys are in most cases constant strings, so that it does not make sense to copy them.

Comment: @yourfriendzak: Actually this code does more than you required. It makes mutable copies where ever possible, for example mutable copies of strings in the hierarchy. If that is not wanted, I can modify the code.

Comment: The code itself doesn't need to be modified, maybe just a comment above the @protocol lines that says "// comment this out to skip over NSStrings"

Answer (score 2):

While Anoop's answer is just fine (I think, I didn't compile it either), if your hierarchy of instances is actually a property list, then you can use [NSPropertyListSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to deserialize a plist with mutable containers and/or leaf nodes.

This would reduce to fewer lines of code and likely be faster than a manual descent through the object graph, but this solution only really makes sense if you are initially deserializing the plist from somewhere.

Comment: NSMutableArray *newArray = (NSMutableArray *)CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFArrayRef)originalArray, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *newDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDictionaryRef)originalDict, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));

Answer (score 1):

For the outer NSDictionary, this will create for 1-level down.

You need to call this in a method, and go on to get all `dict` and `array`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray new];

for(NSDictionary *dict in yourMainDictionary){
   if([outerDict[dict] class]==[NSDictionary class]){
      [dict setObject:outerDict[dict] forKey:dict];
   }
   else if([outerDict[dict] class]==[NSArray class]){
      array[array.count]=outerDict[dict];
   }
}
```

*Not compiler checked. Read as algorithm*

Comment: Why not write this as a recursive method?

Answer (score 1):

If you used some operating system method to create the dictionary: These methods often have a parameter that allows you to create mutable objects. For example, the JSON serialiser class has flags to make all dictionaries and arrays mutable, and to make all NSString objects mutable (NSNumber and NSNull are never mutable).